# My Spring Explorer view shows all projects as empty. What am I missing?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

The projects are visible in the navigator or package view. I am using STS 2.7.1 and Core Spring 3.2.1.

Also, the "Beans support" tab is not visible under (right-click project)  Properties -> Spring.

Comment: This is a very old version of STS.  I'd recommend upgrading.  Also, did this just start happening, or have you had the problem for a while? Any errors in your error log?